# How to split this address '1003 BRILEY PKWY, NASHVILLE, TN'

Tags: mysql, split

```
Select
SUBSTRING_INDEX(OwnerAddress, ',' , -1),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(OwnerAddress, ',' , -2)
,SUBSTRING_INDEX(OwnerAddress, ',' , -3)
From mytable;
```

I want to split address, city and state in mysql from the field "OwnerAddress".  The whole row which is address formatted like this "1003  BRILEY PKWY, NASHVILLE, TN".

Comment: OK, and what is the result of the code you've shown? Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @IMSoP This is the result. I want the city, and address in separate fields like the way 'state'  in the address  got split.


`       ' TN', ' NASHVILLE, TN', '1802  STEWART PL, NASHVILLE, TN'   `

Comment: @IMSoP This is the result. I want the city, and address in separate fields like the way 'state'  in the address  got split.


      ' TN', ' NASHVILLE, TN', '1802  STEWART PL, NASHVILLE, TN'

Comment: Which bits are address, state and city

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(OwnerAddress, ',' , 1) as address,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(OwnerAddress, ',' , 2),',',-1) as city,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(OwnerAddress, ',' , -1) as state 
From mytable;
```